# Dirichlet serie for $\frac{1}{\varphi}$.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\varphi$ the Euler's totient. There are many known formulas to get a closed form of the Dirichlet series associated to $\varphi$ or to related functions. I didn't find one for the function $\kappa(n) = \frac{1}{\varphi(n)}$, the inverse (multiplicatively, not in the set-theoretical sense) of the totient.

This function is clearly multiplicative, so that if we denote by $K$ the Dirichlet series of $\kappa$ we have, in the convergence domain:

$$\begin{aligned}
K(s) &= \prod_p \left(\sum_{e=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{p^{es}\varphi(p^e)}\right)\\
&=\prod_p \left(1+\sum_{e=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{p^{es}p^e(1-p^{-1})}\right)\\
&= \prod_p  \left(1+\sum_{e=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{p^{e(s+1)}(1-p^{-1})}\right)\\
&= \prod_p  1+\frac{p^{-(s+1)}}{(1-p^{-(s+1)})(1-p^{-1})}\\
\end{aligned}$$

But I don't have the feeling it can be expressed in a closed form of classical functions.

Comment: I find something like $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{-s}}{\varphi(n)} =\zeta(s-1) \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1-s}\frac{\mu(n)}{\varphi(n)}$

Comment: I agree but does the (almost) Dirichlet series of the RHS can be written as a closed form of classical functions?

Comment: Of course no. But you can approximate its logarithm in term of $\zeta(sk)$ and show everything you need (zeros, poles, natural boundary, growth, estimate of $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{\varphi(n)}$). And for some integers it has a closed-form.

Comment: I don't clearly see how you get the approximation of its log from your expression, do you expand the RHS as a Eulerian product, take the derivative and identify from the logarithmic derivative?

Comment: I meant $-\log \prod_p (1-\frac{p^{-s}}{1-p^{-1}}) = \sum_{p^k} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}(1-p^{-1})^{-k} = \sum_{p^k} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k} \sum_{m \ge 0} {-k \choose m} p^{-m}$ $
 = \sum_{m \ge 0,k \ge 1} P(sk+m) \frac{{-k \choose m}}{k}= \sum_{m \ge 0,k \ge 1,n\ge 1}  \frac{{-k \choose m}\mu(n)}{kn}\log \zeta(nsk+nm)$ a little messy but the same method works for any Euler product $\prod_p (1+f(p^{-s}))$. And I meant it helps for locating the zeros,poles,singularities (branch points) and the natural boundary on $\Re(s) = 0$

Comment: I see. I understand why it is useful for providing these kind of informations, but I’m slightly surprised that it can allows to compute some closed values ( for instance the simplest s=1 in this expression seems almost worst than the original expression , or I might not see some simplifications ). By the way do you have a reference on the generic method you are referring ?